# Why does my function not run once I run the module and input?

Tags: python-3.x

```
'''
Pig Latin is a program game, which
moves the first letter of the word you entered to the end and adds "ay."
So "Python" becomes "ythonpay."
'''

print ("Pig Latin") #welcoming message for the program.

word = input("Input a word in English ") #user input defined variable

def pigtranslator(): #function that does translation from english to pig language
if 1 > 0: #true
    wordlen = word.len #assigns the length of word to a variable
    translation == word[1:wordlen] + word[0] + 'ay' #translates the word
    print (trasnlation) #prints the translation

else:
    print("The word you've entered is not correct. Please enter a new word")

return
```

After I run this module I'm asked for an input but after I input nothing happenss and the function pigtranslator does not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of that you didn't called your function.You need to add `pigtranslator()` at the end of your module.

```
print ("Pig Latin") #welcoming message for the program.

word = input("Input a word in English ") #user input defined variable

def pigtranslator(): #function that does translation from english to pig language
  if 1 > 0: #true
    wordlen = word.len #assigns the length of word to a variable
    translation == word[1:wordlen] + word[0] + 'ay' #translates the word
    print (trasnlation) #prints the translation

  else:
    print("The word you've entered is not correct. Please enter a new word")

return

pigtranslator()
```

But as a more elegant way you can move the following parts :

```
print ("Pig Latin") #welcoming message for the program.
word = input("Input a word in English ") #user input defined variable
```

to your function and call it using the module :

```
print my_module.pigtranslator()
```

Comment: So calling the function basically runs it and If i want the function to be ran , I should always do it ?  ( like printing variables, I can always define them but unless I print them/echo them I wont see their content, similarly I define functions and they are available but unless I call them they won't run?

Comment: That's great. Once I called the function I found all the other errors in my code (wrong variable, using .len instead of len() and defining a variable with == isntead of =) the program works, thanks!